# Connecting a bare condenser microphone to a RCA cable

Tags: microphone, converter, rca

I just bought a condenser microphone for direct PCB placement (i call it a bare microphone), I know it resists based on air vibrations (sound). So how could I connect it's 2 pins to a RCA (red white yellow) audio cable (so that I can hear it through a speaker)?

Comment: What *are* you really asking? RCA cable? (there is no such thing)  or resistance to voltage? What kind of microphone is this?

Comment: condenser microphone.

Comment: Condenser microphones don't 'resist according to sound'. They generate (tiny) voltages.

Comment: So an amplifier would be of use? What voltage would be safe on the amplifier?

Comment: You need a head amplifier at the microphone to drive the cable, and unless it is an electret you also need a polarizing DC supply. The head amplifier needs an enormous input impedance measured in Gigohms, because the source is a tiny capacitance measured in a few pF. You need to look this up: it's far too broad to answer here.

Answer (score 2):

A microphone is a transducer, a device that converts variations in a physical quantity, such as pressure or brightness, into an electrical signal, or vice versa. You didn't give a link to a datasheet so we have to guess what type it is.

- Coil type microphones work like a loudspeaker in reverse. The diaphragm is physically connected to a coil which moves with the air vibrations in a magnetic field. This induces a voltage on the coil terminals. This small signal is fed to an amplifier circuit to boost the signal strength.
- In condensor or capacitor types the diaphragm is part of a charged capacitor. Movement of the diaphragm causes the voltage across the condenser to change and this can also be amplified. A small bias voltage is required to charge the condenser.

> So how could I connect it's 2 pins to a RCA audio cable?

Solder, screws, bulldog clips, any way you like. (What's an RCA cable anyway?)

> I guess what I am really asking is, how can I turn resistance into voltage?

You can't. You can turn sound vibrations into alternating voltage. That's what a microphone does.

> So how could I connect it's 2 pins to a RCA (red white yellow) audio cable (so that I can hear it through a speaker)?

A microphone signal is very low voltage. You need to:

- Connect it to a screened cable.
- Connect the other end to an amplifier input.
- Connect the amplifier output to a loudspeaker.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fU74YA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Very simplified microphone amplifier circuit. This leaves out power supply, volume control and lots of other information.*

To get started on your journey into audio electronics connect your microphone to a 3.5 mm microphone jack plug and plug it in to your laptop and see if you can get some audio.